# Nginx redirect error

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect all request to nonexistent url (File does not exist: in nginx log) http://example.com/example to index page httt://example.com.

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    access_log off;
    #access_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/example.com-acc main;
    error_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/example.com-err;

    client_max_body_size 256m;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args; # redirect to index
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_buffer_size 16k;
        proxy_buffers 32 16k;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|swf|flv|avi|djvu|mp3|mp4|ogv|3gp|otf)$ {
        root /srv/www/example.com/htdocs/public;
    }

    include vhost.inc.conf;
}
```

But I always get "500 internal error" after I trying to follow the wrong link.

In my error log I've got:

19419 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php", client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"

What's the problem here?

Comment: What is in `vhost.inc.conf`?

Comment: `location ~ /\.git {
    deny all;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

location ~ /\.svn {
    deny all;
}

location ^~ /awstatsicons/ {
    alias /var/www/awstats/icon/;
}`